# Find Azure AD groups that have a sensitivity label applied

Tags: microsoft-graph-groups

We have a requirement to check any group that has used a particular sensitivity label.

I've looked at the [Advanced query capabilities on Azure AD directory objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http) to try to build a filter clause, but I haven't had any luck.

Is this possible? There are +10,000 groups in this tenant, so it's not ideal to call the list groups endpoint without a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Microsoft Graph service-specific throttling limits:

[image]

Please refer this document for reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#pattern

Hope this helps.